# Populate listview with video files on KitKat

Tags: java, android, listview, video, android-4.4-kitkat

I hope somebody can help me.

I display on my app all the recorded video files located on the sd card through a listView. But this doesn't work with the Api 19 (kitkat).My code is this:

```
String selection = MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA + " like?";      
String[] selectionArgs = new String[]{"%"+ VideoRoute + "%"};  
videocursor =    activity.getContentResolver().query(MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,proj, selection, selectionArgs, MediaStore.Video.Media.DATE_TAKEN + "DESC");  
count = videocursor.getCount();

while (videocursor.moveToNext()){    
    ...      
Bitmap bmThumbnail = ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail(video.getUrlMedia(), Thumbnails.MICRO_KIND);       
...   
}
```

Does anyone know how to achieve this with Android KitKat?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please describe in more detail how your code "does not work".  Does it crash?  Does it just not populate the list?  Does it fail to compile?

Comment: It just does not populate the listview, videocursor is empty with count 0, like there's nothing of video files on the sd card.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll post my own answer, in case someone needs help like me with this issue, what worked for me:

```
//with videoList fill de listView
videoList = getFilesKitkat();
```

---

```
public List<Video> getFilesKitkat(){
    int i = 0;
    list.clear();//list is global

    //App package directory in the sd card to get all the files,
    // in my case, there is only mp4 files.
    // /storage/extSdCard/Android/data/<package_name>/files...
    File targetDirector = new File (videosPath);

    File[] files = targetDirector.listFiles();
    int totalFiles = files.length;
    String[] filesToScan = new String[totalFiles];

    //this is to get all the paths in order to pass them to MediaScannerConnection
    for (File file : files){    
        filesToScan[i] = file.getAbsolutePath();
        i++;
    }
    callMediaScanner_kitkat(filesToScan);

    return list;
}

public void callMediaScanner_kitkat(final String[] files) {
    MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(context, files, null, 
            new MediaScannerConnection.OnScanCompletedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScanCompleted(String path, Uri uri) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Log.i("Test", "Scanned " + path);
            getVideosList_kitkat(context, uri);
        }
    });
}

public void getVideosList_kitkat(Context context, Uri contentUri) {
      Cursor cursor = null;
      try { 
          String[] proj = { MediaStore.Video.Media._ID,
                MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA,
                MediaStore.Video.Media.DISPLAY_NAME,
                MediaStore.Video.Media.SIZE, 
                MediaStore.Video.Media.TITLE,
                MediaStore.Video.Media.DATE_MODIFIED};
        cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(contentUri,  proj, null, null, null);

        while (cursor.moveToNext()){
              Video video = new Video();

              int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
              int id = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Video.Media._ID));
              String nombre = (cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Video.Media.TITLE))).toLowerCase();
              video.setName(nombre + XSalesApplication.getActivityContext().getResources().getString(R.string.video_extension));
              video.setId(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Video.Media._ID)));
              video.setSize(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Video.Media.SIZE)));
              video.setUrlMedia(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA)));      video.setlastModified(cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Video.Media.DATE_MODIFIED)));

              Bitmap bmThumbnail = ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail(video.getUrlMedia(), Thumbnails.MICRO_KIND);
              video.setPhotoBitmap(bmThumbnail);

              list.add(video);
        }

      } finally {
        if (cursor != null) {
          cursor.close();
        }
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Before KitKat, public APIs only supported a single primary external storage device, which on some devices can be emulated and backed by internal storage.  Primary external storage devices continue to work the way they always have since API level 1; if you request WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE you have full read/write access across that entire device.

For secondary external storage devices in KitKat, there is limited write access to directories belonging to the running app.

Advantages-

1: apps can take advantage of the extra storage space.

2: users have better visibility into and control over how apps are using their storage space.  (These package-specific directories are surfaced to apps through Context.getExternalFilesDirs(), etc.)

So your code might be giving zero count of videos found.

Comment: Correct, due to this problem this video files are stored in the sd card inside the app package directory, and the url is /storage/extSdCard/Android/data/<com.package>/files/ but still is not finding any video file.